# Why does the list become empty when it is used in another function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

I want to create a subclass from `UITableViewCell`, where it includes the following code:

```
var labelArray = [UILabel]()

convenience init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String, column: Int, array: [Int]) {
    var cell = UITableViewCell(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.init()

    let left_padding = 0

    var labelArray = [UILabel]()
    // populate the labelArray
    println(labelArray) // print the populated Array
}
```

The initialization looks like succeeding and the `labelArray` print the proper content.

However, when I tried to use the populated `labelArray` from within another function, like:

```
func changeLabelWithString(string: String, index: Int) {
    var label = labelArray[index]
    label.text = string
}
```

This passed the compile but hit the runtime error, because the `labelArray[index]` gets the error: `fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer`.

So when I tried to check out the `labelArray` from within the function, then it returns the empty array.

Why does the array become empty after initialization? I retain the `labelArray` with `var labelArray = [UILabel]()` in the first line of the custom class, as I wrote. Also note that I didn't declare it as `weak var` - it's just `var` declaration.

So what am I missing here? This app is written in Xcode 6.1 Beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared `labelArray` in 2 places: inside the method and as an instance variable of the class.  These are 2 distinct things, so that changes to one do not affect the other.  The instance variable didn't *become* empty: it started out that way and never changed.

Also, `init` isn't returning anything (and it isn't supposed to).

Comment: Thanks, that fixed up the issue. As to the second point, I don't return anything using `return` statement. Or you mean I shouldn't populate the instance variable within `init`?

Comment: @Gardecolo: "then it returns the empty array"